# How to rotate bar chart like the example "CPTTestApp-iPhone" provided in core plot?

Tags: core-plot

I am trying to have my bar chart have the same rotate behaviour as in the example provided in core plot. I am using xcode4 and been googling with no luck for a while to get this working . If i copy my code in the example it does work fine, how can I do it for my own project? See images below

#### Portrait

[image: portrait]

#### Landscape

[image: landscape]

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$self.hostingView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);$
```

Credit isn't mine, the answer was also on Stack Overflow somewhere else...can't find it.

PS: Obviously replace `<self.hostingView>` with whatever `CPTGraphHostingView` you allocated to host your graph and plots in.