# How To Rotate or Adjust Graph As Landscape?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, landscape

I have been knocking my head of for almost half a day, but still unable to recognize the solution. Pardon me if it is a lame Question...

**Target:** Always display my graph in landscape mode, regardless of the orientation of the device. I want my x-axis and y-axis to be displayed like shown in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2/screen-shot-2012-05-07-at-5-29-31-pm) figure. How nicely x-axis is taking more space than y-axis to display more data, but no such instruction is mentioned how author did this.

What I have uptill now is:

```cs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

Also in `viewDidLoad`, I tried to rotate the my view -90 degrees:

```cs
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(M_PI * (90) / 180.0));
```

On load, my view looks like below, where `Date` is x-axis and `Calories Burned` is y-axis.

[image: View on Load Figure]

When I rotate simulator, it gives very odd look:

[image: View on Simulator Rotation]

Can please someone tell me how can I adjust this thing? Thanks alot.

---

*Edit after receiving a proper answer:
One more thing I want to mention is that to solve the problem I mentioned in figure 2, just write:

```
myHostingGraph.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

This is a very important line to make orientation work more beautifully. Reference from: [stackoverflow.com/a/10954432/437146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569580/how-to-rotate-bar-chart-like-the-example-cpttestapp-iphone-provided-in-core-pl/10954432#10954432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the whole UIViewController to only landscape with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
              return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
   }
    else return YES;
}
```

And if you really want, when they turn it to portrait just transform/rotate the label and move it to above your graph with, `IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;` `yourLabel.center=CGPointMake(yourGraph.center.x, 10);`

Comment: One more thing I want to mention is that to solve the problem I mentioned in figure 2, just write: `myHostingGraph.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);` . This is a very important line to make orientation work more beautifully. Reference from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10954432/437146